# Cairo-dock ubuntu 14.04 shifts down desktop and windows

Tags: 14.04, cairo-dock

Whenever I start Cairo-dock everything shifts down about 1 and half inches from the top bar.  So for example, if I have my browser open it is no longer flush against the top bar but instead shows some of the desktop background above it.  If I click on the time the calendar shows itself 1 and half inches down from the bar rather than right below the time.  I have updated it, uninstalled it and reinstalled and the problem still continues.